# SQL - Joining tables with similar word to the column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It's my first time asking a question here.

I am basically trying to join a table with a similar word per column.

I tried to Left join the two tables using "Like" but I am not getting the output I want.

I have tblraw as the main source which I need to find to the tblsrc table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3oMY.jpg

and I have tblsrc for the tblraw to lookup.

![https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BT32.png]

and here is the output I came up with. As you can see the row 1 "Code" column is null. the value should be looked-up on the tblsrc and having the value "D5Water 500ml (Enddure)D5Water 500ml (Enddure)bots."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXaZe.png

is there a way to looked-up the similar words of the column in the tblraw to tblsrc?

I made a script for you to test.

```
declare @tblraw Table
(
D varchar(100),
P varchar(100),
U varchar(100)
)

declare @tblsrc Table
(
Code Varchar(100)
)


insert into @tblraw(D,P,U) values('RHEGIUM','D5Water 500ml (Enddure)','bots.'),
('RHEGIUM','Butamirate 50mg tab (Mefecod) 100''s','bxs.'),
('RHEGIUM','Cetirizine drops (Reax)','bots.'),
('RHEGIUM','Mefenamic Susp. (Infamix)','bots.'),
('RHEGIUM','Nicardipine amp. (Nicard)','amps.'),
('RHEGIUM','Nystatin  susp. (Nysaph 12ml)','bots.'),
('RHEGIUM','Sambong 500ml  (urisam) ','tabs'),
('RHEGIUM','Clopidogrel 75mg  (Saphlopid) ','tabs'),
('RHEGIUM','Metformin 500mg  (Saphormin) ','tabs'),
('Arguelles Pharmacy','Salbutamol + Iratropium (Salresp)','bxs.')

select * from @tblraw

insert into @tblsrc(Code) Values('D5Water 500ml (Enddure)D5Water 500ml (Enddure)bots.'),
('Butamirate 50mg tab (Mefecod) 100''sButamirate 50mg tab (Mefecod) 100''sbxs.'),
('Butamirate 50mg tab (Mefecod) 100''sButamirate 50mg tab (Mefecod) 100''sbxs'),
('Cetirizine drops (Reax)'),
('Mefenamic Susp. (Infamix)Mefenamic Susp. (Infamix)bots.'),
('Sambong 500ml  (urisam)Sambong 500ml  (urisam)tabs'),
('RheqiumClopidogrel 75mg tab. (Clopend) 100''sbx.'),
('LPP PharmaClopidogrel 75mg (Clopida)tabs.'),
('Metformin 500mg tab  (Saphormin) 100''sMetformin 500mg tab  (Saphormin) 100''sbxs.'),
('RheqiumMetformin 500mg (Adiac) 100''sbxs.'),
('Salbutamol + Iratropium (Salresp)Salbutamol + Iratropium (Salresp)bxs.')


select * from @tblsrc

--This is the script I came up with.
SELECT A.*,CODE FROM @tblraw A
LEFT JOIN @tblsrc B
--ON A.D+A.P+A.U like '%' +B.CODE + '%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
ON A.P like '%' +B.CODE + '%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Comment: Use Inner Join instead of Left join. And you are good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are using left join. Left join returns all the values from A and matches them with corresponding values in B. If there are no matching values in B, the column value is null. 
   Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)
2. If you want to see only matched values from both tables, use inner join. 
   Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)
3. You logic is wrong. Table B has more detailed strings, so A will almost never match. 
   If you want to match with like keyword, you should prefer to use it to match a more 
   detailed string (more characters) with a less detailed string (less characters). 
   Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

The query below should work

```
   SELECT A.*,CODE FROM @tblraw A
        INNER JOIN @tblsrc B
        --ON A.D+A.P+A.U like '%' +B.CODE + '%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
        ON B.Code like '%' + A.P + '%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```